# Resource impact of using C# FileSystem Watcher on the whole drive appears to be null, is there a downside?

Tags: c#

So for a project I'd like to monitor the whole file system. Windows 7.

I did a test:

1. Booted fresh, waited a few minutes
2. Copied to another folder on the same partition about 2 GB of files and timed it
3. Deleted the folder, restarted, waited a few minutes
4. Started the file system monitor and copied

It took the exact same time, CPU usage wasn't noticeable higher, the RAM usage of the FileSystem Watcher console app was negligible.

Am I missing something? Is there a case in which it might slow down my server?

Because I didn't see any issues and the benefits for me would be huge.

Comment: The watching doesn't cost a lot since it simply hooks into the file system's activities. So the size or complexity of the watched drive doesn't matter. Depending on how many FSWs you install or how massive the activities get you may see more load, but I too found it a rather efficient way to protocol changes..

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that you will likely not receive notifications for all file system changes in you case. It does not slow down your system because the notifications are asynchronous but there's a limit to the buffer space allocated for these messages. The buffer can be enlarged but it is expensive non-paged memory and it will overflow anyway if the file system changes get large large enough. Here's what the MSDN documentation says: 'If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow'.